Angular Forms - No Data From Html Retrived
Hi there i have a problem with angular forms, i add simple list of forms to my html
     <div class="tasks-section">
        <h2>Zadania</h2>
        <button type="button" class="addButton" (click)="addTask()">Dodaj</button>
        <div *ngFor="let task of tasks.controls; let i = index">
          <div [formGroupName]="i" class="task-item">
            <div>
              <label for="taskName{{ i }}">Nazwa:</label>
              <input id="taskName{{ i }}" formControlName="name" type="text" required />
            </div>
    
            <div>
              <label for="taskCode{{ i }}">Typ:</label>
              <ng-multiselect-dropdown formControlName="taskCode" id="taskCode{{ i }}"
                [placeholder]="'Wybierz Typ'"
                [data]="taskCodes"
                [settings]="dropdownSettingsTaskCodes"
              ></ng-multiselect-dropdown>
            </div>
    
            <div>
              <label for="taskDescription{{ i }}">Opis:</label>
              <input id="taskDescription{{ i }}" formControlName="description" type="text" required />
            </div>
    
            <div>
              <label for="taskBanner{{ i }}">Kupon propnowany (Opcjonalne):</label>
              <ng-multiselect-dropdown formControlName="proposedBannerId" id="taskBanner{{ i }}"
                [placeholder]="'Wybierz Kupon'"
                [data]="banners"
                [settings]="dropdownSettingsBanners"
              ></ng-multiselect-dropdown>
            </div>  
          </div>
          <button type="button" (click)="removeTask(i)">Usuń</button>
        </div>
      </div>

i add this like this
  get tasks(): FormArray {
    return this.actionForm.get('tasks') as FormArray;
  }

  addTask(): void {
    const taskGroup = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      taskCode: [null, Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      proposedBannerId: [[]]
    });
    this.tasks.push(taskGroup);
  }

  removeTask(index: number): void {
    this.tasks.removeAt(index);
  }

In ngOnInit i create main form
     this.actionForm = this.fb.group({
        storeId: [null, Validators.required],
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        salary: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]],
        tasks: this.fb.array([])
      });

Problem is with data retrived from form, in actionForm data is correct, but in tasks all fields are null

formArrayName="tasks" this was missed, to close

have you solved the issue? please clarify
